# How to create a new DraftInlineStyle?

Tags: draftjs

I have tried to create a new state with Modifier.insertText and the third argument is supposed to a draftInlineStyle

```
let ncs = Modifier.insertText(contentStates, selections, superscriptVar, ["BOLD"]);
```

This does give bold but when i try to change the style later on it doesn't change. I have figured out this is because draftInlineStyle is supposed to be a constructor. So how do I create a draftInlineStyle constructor if i am supposed to pass a draftInlineStyle constructor? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What the error do you have in the console?

Comment: The error is 'Uncaught TypeError: currentStyle.add is not a function'. When I console logged draftInlineStyles for other blocks, it gives an object, so when I am passing it as ["BOLD"], I guess the problem is that the functions associated with the object is not getting passed  (since the object is replaced by ["BOLD"] and therefore draftjs cannot change the style after setting the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`OrderedSet.of`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedSet/of) from Immutable.js.

```
let ncs = Modifier.insertText(
  contentStates,
  selections,
  superscriptVar,
  OrderedSet.of('BOLD')
);
```

If you want to apply many styles, pass them as arguments: `OrderedSet.of('BOLD', 'ITALIC')`

Check the simplified demo in the hidden snippet below:

```js
const {Editor, RichUtils, Modifier, SelectionState, EditorState} = Draft;
const { OrderedSet } = Immutable;

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
  }
  
  insertTextHandler = (nameOfCustomStyle) => {
    const currentSelection = this.state.editorState.getSelection();
    const currentContent = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
    
    if (!currentSelection.isCollapsed()) return;

   const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(currentContent, currentSelection, 'INSERTED TEXT', OrderedSet.of('BOLD'));
  
    const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
      this.state.editorState,
      newContentState,
      'change-inline-style'
    );
  
   this._handleChange(newEditorState)
  }
  
  toggleBoldStyle = () => {
    this._handleChange(
      RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
        this.state.editorState,
        'BOLD'
      )
    );
  }
  
  _handleChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({ editorState });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container-root">
          <Editor
            placeholder="Type away :)"
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            onChange={this._handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => this.insertTextHandler()}>
          INSERT TEXT
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.toggleBoldStyle()}>
          TOGGLE BOLD STYLE FOR SELECTED TEXT
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-root'))
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.public-DraftEditor-content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.7.0/Draft.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draft-js/0.10.0/Draft.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Hey I need a quick help, how do we create ContentBlock? I guess we have to use `map` from immutablejs. What's the format?